# Row Level Security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, linq-to-sql

How do you prevent a user to only update their row in the database.

For example:
A user is responsible for a school. They can change fields for that school, but only that school.

Thus: SchoolId, OwnerID, Name, PhoneNumber

I've implemented a function that:
CanEditSchool(SchoolID) If the user isn't the owner of the specific school it throws an exception.

Is there a better solution? I'm using linq2sql as the orm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you handle your datacontext, you can use LoadOptions on the datacontext.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386915(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One solution, which doesn't seem optimal, would be to create a view for the user, containing only the school under their jurisdiction:

```
CREATE VIEW `v_jimmy` AS
    SELECT * FROM `schools`
    WHERE SchoolId = 5;
```

Comment: I don't think that is at all usable in the OP's application.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a view, but a Table Value Function passing in the user's ID and returning only the horizontally partitioned values could be worth considering. With that, you could remove select permissions on the schools table and access it through LINQ to SQL as you would any other table, just passing in a parameter for the ID. Updates get trickier (or use Stored Procs). You do loose access to server indexes though.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action should check your security function to assure that the logged-in user is able to edit the item in question. If not, you should send them to a 'permission denied' type of page/view.

Your `CanEditSchool` function does not need to throw an exception, though. It's name suggests that it would return a `bool`; `true` if they can edit it, `false` if not.